# Angular 7 iterate json by button click

Tags: html, arrays, json, angular, typescript

As I mentioned in title, I want to iterate by button click over my json response. See below my json file:

```
{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Słownictwo",
    "flashcardLists": [
        {
            "id": 17,
            "frontside": "dasfasdv",
            "backside": "csdascd"

        },
        {
            "id": 18,
            "frontside": "dsadsaad",
            "backside": "sdasdadad"
        },
        {
            "id": 19,
            "frontside": "dasdsadd",
            "backside": "sdaddsa"
        }
    ]
}
```

FlashcardHTML:

```
<div  class="flip-container" (click)="flip()" [class.flipped]="flipped" >
    <mat-card-header></mat-card-header>
    <mat-card-content *ngFor="let flashcard of flashcardLists" class="flipper">
    <mat-card class="front">
       {{flashcard.frontside}}
    </mat-card>
    <mat-card class="back">
      {{flashcard.backside}}
    </mat-card>
    </mat-card-content>
</div>
```

I have component where in one time I want only one "frontside" and "backside".
Next, it will be replaced by button clicked which will increase counter but I don't know how to do that. I tried something like this `flashcard[0].frontside`, but it was KO. Maybe someone has encountered the same problem and can help me.

For all answers thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want to show all card at the same time, and on button click all of them change to the next one? or do you want to show only one card, that on button click will change to the next one? It looks like from your code, that your view contains a list of all cards...

Comment: There is one card changing it side by clicking it. I have another button to iterate

Comment: <button (click)="iterate()" class="btn-flashcard" mat-button mat-raised-button  id="previous" >Następna</button>

Comment: <mat-card-content *ngFor="let flash of flashcardLists" class="flipper">
     <mat-card class="front">
       {{flash[i].frontside}}
     </mat-card>
     <mat-card class="back">
      {{flash[i].backside}}
     </mat-card>
   </mat-card-content>

Comment: Still I think I don't understand, you want each card to be able to flip from front to back, and from back to front?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand properly, you wanna be flipping a single card.

Something like this should do:

```
<mat-card-content *ngFor="let flashcard of flashcardLists" class="flipper">
  <mat-card [class.front]="!flashcards[i].isFlipped"
            [class.back]="flashcards[i].isFlipped"
            (click)="flashcards[i].isFlipped = !flashcards[i].isFlipped "
            >
     {{ flashcards[i].isFlipped ? flashcard.backside : flashcard.frontside }}
  </mat-card>
</mat-card-content>
```

Just add this map of card states to y0our component:

```
flashcards: { [key: string]: boolean } = {};
```

Comment: if clicked in grey area it flipped but next values i want when i clicked button "Nastepna"

Comment: I forget to tell that in one case it work. i can flip but i dont load the next value because i cant iterate

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an `*ngFor` in your `mat-card-content`, instead bind it to a `flipCard` variable, which will change on button iterate click. As for the front or back, use another variable `isFront` which you'll update on flip button click. something like this:

**component.html**:

```
<mat-card>
  <mat-card-header></mat-card-header>
  <mat-card-content class="flipper">
    <div class="front" *ngIf="isFront">
      {{flashcard.frontside}}
    </div>
    <div class="back" *ngIf="!isFront">
      {{flashcard.backside}}
    </div>
  </mat-card-content>
  <mat-card-actions>
    <button (click)="iterate()" class="btn-flashcard" mat-button mat-raised-button id="previous">
      Następna
    </button>
    <button mat-button (click)="flip()" [class.flipped]="flipped">LIKE</button>
    <button mat-button>SHARE</button>
  </mat-card-actions>
</mat-card>
```

**component.ts**:

```
flashcardList: any[] // use your flashCard class instead of any
flashcard: any; // use your flashCard class instead of any
isFront = true;

ngOnInit() {
  // init first card
  // flashcard = first card
}

iterate() {
  // logic for getting the next card
  // flashcard = next card
  // e.g.
  let index = this.flashcardList.indexOf(this.flashcard);
  this.flashcard = this.flashcardList[index + 1];
}

flip() {
  this.isFront = !this.isFront;
}
```

Comment: I think I got you wrong, do you want each card to be able to flip from front to back, and from back to front?

Comment: I have a list in json of flashcard and I want to iterate over it , I thought there is sth like flash[i] and in my iterator func i++

Comment: Added an example code for you in iterate func in my answer